# Using MagicalRecord with NSUndoManager

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

As we know, on iOS, NSManagedObjectContext doesn't come with a default NSUndoManager instance. In case we want to support undo/redo in Core Data, we need to instantiate our own.

Here's what I wrote in my appDelegate:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[MagicalRecord setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack];
NSUndoManager *undo = [[NSUndoManager alloc] init];
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context] setUndoManager:undo];

return YES;
}
```

but later on, when I observer:

```
NSLog(@"%p", [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context].undoManager);
```

the result is always nothing, which means the undoManager has never been instantiated. Can anyone advise the right way of adding undo/redo support while working with MagicalRecord.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following code doesn't work, because you create a new context with MR_context. This new context will be deallocated after the statement.

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context] setUndoManager:undo];
```

You want to set the undo manager of the default context

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] setUndoManager:undo];
```